# Moving from 80gig raid to 500gig

Tags: raid, windows-server-2003-r2

A client has a 80gig hd in a raid set, he would like to increase his hard drive to at least 500gig. What is the best way to do this? He would like to keep all his configuration, he has windows 2003

Comment: Use hard drives. What exactly is your question?

Comment: my question is, is there a way that the client can expand his 80gig drive to 500 gig drive in his raid set, without losing the configuration of his system, keep in mind that he is running windows 2003

Comment: What kind of raid, hardware/software.  If hardware, then what hardware do you have exactly.  You mentioned you tried making a backup, you could ask a question about how to resolve the error.

Comment: sorry, I will get more information by tomorrow.

Answer (score 5):

Back up the system. Create the new RAID set. Restore to the new disks. Extend the partition.

Comment: As simple as that. You could also do a disk clone to the new RAID system.

Comment: They did try backing up the system using acronis, but when they try to access the back up they are not able to.  They were wondering what is the best backup software to use in this situation?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not willing to do your job for you.

Comment: I'll do your job for you, but it'll cost you $1800USD/day.